# unable to import module pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip

I am working on OS X
Ive looked at many different threads and haven't found a solution. Maybe I haven't been installing things properly from the start either. I want to import the module pyautogui into my project but it is saying it can't find it. I did a pip install in terminal and in the pycharmterminal as well. I have found the file directory and verified that it is available. But yet I am still not able to access it in my project. On some of the threads I read something about **init**.py, do I need to put that in my project. If so is there code in that py file or do I just create a python file named **init**.py

Comment: Can you pls post the error that your are getting

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS and some Linux distros, you may need to type `pip3 install package-name`.